# Differential histogram bin calculation

Tags: density-function, histogram

I want to be able to minimize a difference between two distributions $P(x|\theta)$ and $Q$.  I can choose Q (e.g. to be a Gaussian normal), but $P(x|\theta)$ is an unknown distribution, so I am currently using a histogram.  (It appears to be multimodal for one thing.)

That is, I have some parameterized function producing data for values at each $x$, $f(x,\theta)$, and $P(x|\theta)$ is the PDF of values produced by that function.

In order to calculation e.g. the KL divergence, I can make a normalized histogram of Q and P, and calculate the log ratio per bin.  However, this histogram approach as far as I can tell does not allow me to calculate derivative of this divergence with respect to $\theta$.  For one thing, the bin calculations $P_i$ are sums of inequalities (i.e. $P_i(x|\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_j^n B_i(f(x_j,\theta)),$ where $B_i(x)=\begin{cases}1&b_{iw}\geq x>b_{(i+1)w}\\0&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$), and this does not appear to be differentiable w.r.t. $\theta$ even if $f(x_j,\theta)$ is differentiable.

I thought about maybe replacing the bin calculation $B$ with a function that weights the value according to a very thin Gaussian centered on the bin center.  That would allow calculating a derivative for each bin, but I can't find any references to any such method.

Am I off on the wrong foot here?  I just want to be able to calculate a gradient w.r.t. to the difference between an arbitrary PDF and my Gaussian normal, but I can only find ways to do it that involve either (1) fitting a known distribution, or (2) training a discriminator, which I'd like to avoid.  Is there some way to estimate the log-P/Q ratio that is just an empirical calculation, and is differentiable?

**Edit:** Okay after a bit more research I discovered that this idea of multiplying values by a Gaussian kernel actually works well, and is called kernel density estimation.  Cool!